# Convert multiple nodes in xml to List<string> (C#)

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<termsAndConditions>
  <logo>
    logo1.gif
  </logo>
  <link>
    https://www.mysite.co.uk/Terms%20and%20Conditions.pdf
  </link>
  <paragraphs>
    <text>
      I accept that all the information I have provided is truthful and accurate and I understand that all the information I have provided will be checked and verified. I acknowledge that I have read and accepted all the Terms and Conditions of the site’s Parking Regulations, for full details click here.
    </text>
    <text>
      Paragraph 2
    </text>
    <text>
       Paragraph 3
    </text>
    <text>
       Paragraph 4
    </text>
  </paragraphs>
</termsAndConditions>
```

Now I can convert a node to a string using the following:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("\\termConditionsExample.xml");
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/termsAndConditions/logo");
string myString = node.InnerText;
```

But how can I do this for the "paragraphs/text" in the xml file to turn them into a List type? I have tried using the different DocumentElement mwthods such as one below, but it does not work:

```
List<string> paragraphs = new List<string>();
            foreach(var temp in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                paragraphs.Add(temp.ToString());
            }
```

I know this one does not take any arguments so is wrong. I just don't know which one to use...

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using serialization / de-serialization would allow you to do this trivially?

Comment: @C.Knight I am new to this. Let me look up de-serialization and see if that helps me. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find LINQ-to-XML to be easier to work with for things like this (e.g. `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`).

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("\\termConditionsExample.xml");
IEnumerable<string> textValues = xdoc.Descendants("text").Select(e => e.Value);
```

Xml Deserialization may also be an appropriate approach, as C. Knight mentions in comments.

Comment: I am comfortable with LINQ so this was the best method for me!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `XmlDocument.SelectNodes` and `XmlNode.InnerText`:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/termsAndConditions/paragraphs/text"))
  paragraphs.Add(node.InnerText.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use XPath with the `XDocument` class:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(filename);

var result =
    document
        .XPathSelectElements("termsAndConditions/paragraphs/text")
        .Select(x => x.Value.Trim())
        .ToList();
```

It allows you to select the `text` elements that are in the specified path only (not all the `text` elements in the whole xml file).

Make sure you import the `System.Xml.XPath` namespace like this:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
```